# how to show coupon code in order summary even though it doesn't contain any discount in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

i am using coupon code for my campaign purpose, so i don't want to give any discount on that coupon, but if not giving any discount on coupon code its not showing in the order summary in checkout page even thought its applied.

How can i show that in the order summary in checkout page if coupon code doesn't contain any actual discount.